# What is the best way to mock React child components with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to write a test to mock a child component in a React component hierarchy using Jest. One of Jests main features is mocking functions to reduce test complexity but I cant find a straightforward way to mock child components. I can mock a parent component imported from a module OK the problem I have is mocking a child. Sorry I cant provide a codesandbox or similar as there are a few outstanding issues between csb and jest integration. Other thing to note is that I am using react testing library for rendering and assertions.

A very simple component hierarchy:

```
// ./features/test-samples/tree.js
export const Child = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Child</h1>
    )
}

export const Tree = () => {
    return (<>
        <h1>Tree</h1>
        <Child/>
    </>)
}
```

Both of the following tests succeed.

```
// tree.test.js
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Tree } from './features/test-samples/tree';

describe.only('Test <Tree/> component', () => {
  // test success
  test("test entire render tree", () => {
    const { getByText } = rtlRender(<Tree />);
    expect(getByText(/Tree/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByText(/Child/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  // test success
  test("test mocked parent", () => {
    jest.doMock('./features/test-samples/tree', () => {
      return { 
        Tree: jest.fn(() => <div>Mocked Tree</div>),
      }
    });
    const { Tree } = require('./features/test-samples/tree'); 
    const { getByText } = rtlRender(<Tree />);
    expect(getByText(/Mocked Tree/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
})
```

This doesnt work. How can I write jest test to render parent (Tree) and mock child?

```
  import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
  import { Tree } from './features/test-samples/tree';

  ...
 
  test("test mock child", () => {
    const actualModule = jest.requireActual('./features/test-samples/tree');
    jest.doMock('./features/test-samples/tree', () => {
      return {
        ...actualModule,
        Child: jest.fn(() => <div>Mocked Child</div>),
      }
    });
    const { Tree } = require('./features/test-samples/tree'); 
    const { getByText } = rtlRender(<Tree />);
    expect(getByText(/Mocked Child/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

error:

```
Test <Tree/> › test mock child

    mockConstructor(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

      106 |     });
      107 |     const { Tree } = require('./features/test-samples/tree');
    > 108 |     const { getByText } = rtlRender(<Tree />);
          |                           ^
      109 |     expect(getByText(/Child/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
      110 |   });
      111 | })
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to mock the child component? Since it's not exposed outside the file this implies it's an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. This is a really simple case but a child component may contain complex async processes that unnecessary for rendering other parts of a component tree. Any mocked function or component is essentially implementation.

Comment: If the component is that complex why is it hidden inside another file? It makes it difficult to test in isolation, bloats source files, and leads to the problem you're asking about. This sounds like an organizational, not technical, issue.

Comment: I concur this is a more of a learning exercise to understand mocks than a real-world implementation. I have exported the child to allow for testing and I still cannot override the Child component.